# Is it possible to see how your app looks in all devices?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I am developing an app and it looks good in my android phone. How can I be sure it also looks good in other android devices (smartphones, tablets, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this video from Google I/O 2012 which shows a new feature in Eclipse which displays your app on different screens from different devices.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Erd2k6EKxCQ (~min 19:00)